# How do RSS news aggregators categorize data?

Tags: rss

How do news aggregators like flipboard put their articles into categories like "political, "business", etc? I have searched for this but find no results. I imagine it could be done manually, but I find this very unlikely considering the number of feeds. Is there a public database that contains a list of RSS feeds by category? If not, how is this accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a complicated, multi-step process, but in general:

1. Tokenize the data into paragraphs, sentences, and words. http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml is an example of a tool that can accomplish this. http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/ is another example.
2. Once tokenized, throw out non-specific, general words (also known as "stop words"), such as "a", "the", "ha", "lol", "omg", etc. The tokenizers generally have methods builtin that can identify these and dispose of them.
3. Identify n-grams (words that go together). For example, the words "Bay" and "Area" are two words, but they are often considered a single word "Bay Area". You'll need to identify entities like this to categorize correctly.
4. Group the remaining items by parts of speech. This may be handy for example, to throw out verbs, adverbs, and only use nouns and adjectives for your category classifications.
5. Finally, slice and dice your data by category.